# Assign Amazon S3 access permissions to a specific group of users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a structure in IAM as below.

- Group1 contains User1, User2.
- Group2 contain User3, User4.

I want to give S3 read permissions (to a particular folder in S3) to Group1. In future users may increase. Adding Canonical id to S3 object may difficult in future. So in that way I want to decrease manual effort. Is anyone have good solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach an inline policy to the group `Group 1` like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will allow only the users in `Group 1` to access S3 objects inside `my-bucket` bucket.